# Wrap the id of list item and save it in table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a list of items inside table cells, in each cell I have a list item.
What I want?
When I save the table I want to save the id of each list item into the cell that the list item inside it.
Like this:

```
<td><li id='itemID'>contents</li></td>
```

and I want to save this:

```
<td>itemID</td>
```

Any way to do that?

Comment: You aren't allowed to put `<li>`s in `<td>`s https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.find()` and `.attr()` as shown below.

```
$("td").each(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).find('li').attr('id'));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmzRV/637/)

Comment: Worked.Thank you very much.

Comment: @RawanMansour..happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

An important point to note is that your HTML is invalid. You cannot have an `li` element as a child of a `td`, it must be contained in either an `ul` or `ol`.

Once you've fixed that you can provide a function to `text()` which you call on the `td`. You can then traverse the DOM and return the `id` of the child `li` - assuming there is only one, or you only want to read the `id` of the first one found:

```js
$('td').text(function() {
  return $(this).find('li').prop('id');
});
```

Comment: yes I know that sir, but my tool is to drag drop list items just in ui ,but in the save I want a valid HTML and remove the list items; for this reason I asked the question.Thank you.

Comment: In that case it would be simpler to amend the drag/drop logic to insert valid HTML, instead of inserting invalid HTML which you then have to correct later

Comment: I'd suggest finding a better one then. Barebones jQueryUI would work.